# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document. old project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Visual studio 2005 , win 7

Received a solution of a former programmer , and trying to debug it.

Marked a breakpoint in "Form.h", but it wont break. instead the remark "The breakpoint will not currently...." .

I have looked at the answers available but none of them works for me. 
How can I tell which module specifically is missing for it to work?

[image]

Comment: You provide no info at all so it's impossible to help. C# or C++? `.h` files are C++ headers. If you meant to use the C++ tag, where did you put the breakpoint and what does the code there do? You can't put a breakpoint on a declaration for example, or an unused header file. The message doesn't mean that there's anything missing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your'e right , I edited it and I hope this helps more